# Condensing if statements to give more accurate output

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, error-handling

I'm trying to write a simple if-statement that depends on a set of conditions (the occurences in a list being 0) however I have encountered bugs when two of my conditions are both 0, only one of the statements is displayed.

```
if let1 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",a, "\n")
elif let2 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",b, "\n")
elif let3 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",c, "\n")
```

I've tried using or statements but am unable to produce the desired output informing the user that one, two or three of their inputs may not be in the body of text used in the rest of my program.

Apologies for the lack of succint terminology as I'm very new to programming.

Thanks

EDIT: Thank you for the replies but I should have given the full function...

```
def segment_sequence(mycorpus, letter1, letter2, letter3):
    corpus_string = "".join(mycorpus)
    a = letter1
    b = letter2
    c = letter3
    d = a + b
    e = b + c
    let1 = corpus_string.count(a)
    let2 = corpus_string.count(b)
    let3 = corpus_string.count(c)
    let1let2 = corpus_string.count(d)
    let2let3 = corpus_string.count(e)
    print(let1,let2,let3)
    if let1 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",a, "\n")
    if let2 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",b, "\n")
    if let3 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",c, "\n")
    break
    else:
        trans_prob1 = let1let2/let1
        trans_prob2 = let2let3/let2
        if trans_prob1 > trans_prob2:
            print('Here is the proposed boundary given the training corpus:\n')
            print('Proposed end of one word:' ,d,'\n')
            print('Proposed beginning of new word:' ,c,'\n')
        elif trans_prob2 > trans_prob1:
            print('Here is the proposed boundary given the training corpus:\n')
            print('Proposed end of one word: ',e,'\n')
            print('Proposed beginning of new word: ',a,'\n')
        elif trans_prob1 == trans_prob2:
            print('Both ',d,' and ',e,' are equally possible word endings')
        return()
```

the problem with using if instead of elif is that it doesn't break and I then get errors for division by 0. I'm not looking for anything too complicated just a simple and accurate user error message.

Thank you again

Comment: Try changing the `elif` to just a regular `if`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if elif works like, it check condition where it will get true condition,, it will break after that. So you have to use if only.

```
if let1 == 0:
   print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",a, "\n")
if let2 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",b, "\n")
if let3 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",c, "\n")
```

Comment: Hi please see edit, using if statements stops the function breaking and creates division errors

Answer (score 1):

Istead of using `elif` try using `if` as below:

```
if let1 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",a, "\n")
if let2 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",b, "\n")
if let3 == 0:
    print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",c, "\n")
```

Comment: Hi please see edit, using if statements stops the function breaking and creates division errors

Answer (score 0):

If you want the condition to be tested for each case, do not use elif:

Further, in order to ensure that your function aborts when a case is triggered, which would cause a division by zero, I added a flag and a test to exit after the battery of tests.

```
def segment_sequence(mycorpus, letter1, letter2, letter3):
    corpus_string = "".join(mycorpus)
    a = letter1
    b = letter2
    c = letter3
    d = a + b
    e = b + c
    let1 = corpus_string.count(a)
    let2 = corpus_string.count(b)
    let3 = corpus_string.count(c)
    let1let2 = corpus_string.count(d)
    let2let3 = corpus_string.count(e)
    print(let1,let2,let3)

    must_abort = False

    if let1 == 0:
       print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",a, "\n")
        must_abort = True
    if let2 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",b, "\n")
        must_abort = True
    if let3 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",c, "\n")
        must_abort = True

    if must_abort:
        return

    # no need for else any longer here.
    trans_prob1 = let1let2/let1
    trans_prob2 = let2let3/let2
    if trans_prob1 > trans_prob2:
        print('Here is the proposed boundary given the training corpus:\n')
        print('Proposed end of one word:' ,d,'\n')
        print('Proposed beginning of new word:' ,c,'\n')
    elif trans_prob2 > trans_prob1:
        print('Here is the proposed boundary given the training corpus:\n')
        print('Proposed end of one word: ',e,'\n')
        print('Proposed beginning of new word: ',a,'\n')
    elif trans_prob1 == trans_prob2:
        print('Both ',d,' and ',e,' are equally possible word endings')
    return
```

Now, each case is evaluated and acted upon, regardless of whether a previous condition was met.

#### refactoring the abort cases outside the main function:

```
def segment_sequence(mycorpus, letter1, letter2, letter3):
    corpus_string = "".join(mycorpus)
    a = letter1
    b = letter2
    c = letter3
    d = a + b
    e = b + c
    let1 = corpus_string.count(a)
    let2 = corpus_string.count(b)
    let3 = corpus_string.count(c)
    let1let2 = corpus_string.count(d)
    let2let3 = corpus_string.count(e)
    print(let1,let2,let3)

    if must_abort(let1, let2, let3):
        return

    trans_prob1 = let1let2/let1
    trans_prob2 = let2let3/let2
    if trans_prob1 > trans_prob2:
        print('Here is the proposed boundary given the training corpus:\n')
        print('Proposed end of one word:' ,d,'\n')
        print('Proposed beginning of new word:' ,c,'\n')
    elif trans_prob2 > trans_prob1:
        print('Here is the proposed boundary given the training corpus:\n')
        print('Proposed end of one word: ',e,'\n')
        print('Proposed beginning of new word: ',a,'\n')
    elif trans_prob1 == trans_prob2:
        print('Both ',d,' and ',e,' are equally possible word endings')
    return


def must_abort(let1, let2, let3):
    abort = False
    if let1 == 0:
       print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",a, "\n")
        abort = True
    if let2 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",b, "\n")
        abort = True
    if let3 == 0:
        print("Segmentation unavailable as corpus does not contain the following letter ",c, "\n")
        abort = True
    return abort
```

Comment: Hi please see edit, using if statements stops the function breaking and creates division errors